# How to sort by number of votes in another table?

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate I have a table/class Question and a table/class Vote. Vote.questionId is a foreign key for Question.id.

I want to sort the question by the number of votes.

I am executing

```
session.createQuery("from Question q, Vote v where q.id = v.questionId group by q.id order by count(v) desc")
```

But I get "could not execute query"

Comment: I don't know about Hibernate, but in SQL, you cannot use count(v) - use count(*) or count(v.questionId) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using groups you'll need to select fields specifically just like in SQL, so your query will look like:

```
select q.id, q.title, count(v) from Question q, Vote v where q.id = v.questionId 
 group by q.id, q.title
 order by count(v) desc
```

cheers!

Comment: also, make sure the fields you're using in the select are defined in the group (except aggregate function, such as count).